# What is this permanent connection to Microsoft by Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process

Here is a screenshot of Windows Explorer looked deep into using process explorer.

I am not sure of the why a connection is required to Explorer? My OneDrive has been disabled and nothing's happening in the Explorer too. Can anyone let me know more about why msft is connected here?

[image: shot]

Comment: now? @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 may not be the proper word usage but hope you get the question of my context here.

Comment: What steps did you take to disable OneDrive?    Which edition of Windows 10 is this?

Comment: windows 10 home edition, and I killed all the processes connected to one drive and i have been monitoring to see if its on back but no, and nothing in the background (one drive) is running.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  i Disagree with your answer and this might simply lead to less answers to the post thinking its duplicate please remove it.

Comment: It's a duplicate question as far as I'm concerned.  If you'd like to request it be reopened, please feel free to click "reopen" if it is available, or "Flag" to flag a moderator and request it be looked at.  And/or earn some more rep, and go place [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question in an attempt to  get better/different answers.

Comment: I also would agree this question is indeed a duplicate of that question, and the existing answer to that question, does indeed explain the behavior as described in this question.